# Push notification not supporting existing app Id?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, bundle

Hi I have one iOS App in App store,so when i create that App id i didnt checked "Push notification" (didnt selected that option).Its almost 3 months ,but now  i want to add push notification in a new version 1.4 .But am not able to enable pushnotiication now.?? Is there any way to fix this? 
my bundle identifies in the form of `company.exampleApp`

Or i need to upload it as a new APP?

[image]

Please help.

Comment: If you are going to enable it, either way you need to send updated iPA to itunesconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to go to edit App ID and follow the steps to enable push notifications. Afterwards, you need to get profile again and then create the IPA with updated profile.
If you are using Urban Airship then you also need to change the flag value to YES for "inProduction" in AirshipConfig.plist file.

Comment: Once we create one id in iTunesConnect,we cannot change that for same app .

Comment: @Bangalore Its not need to change the id; Just EDIT it. There is an Edit option present.

Answer (score 0):

You click edit button.

[image]

Then enable push notification, Then generation certification for that.

[image]

After the download your provision file again from the portal replace it with your existing in xcode or simple refresh provision in xcode account setting.

Comment: Once we create one id in iTunesConnect,we cannot change that for same app .

Comment: I am not understand what you trying to say.

Comment: simply i created one app,i released 3 versions .in 4rth version i need push notification. But my app id in (bundle identifier) iTunesConnect is" company.exampleapp"  but push notification need atleast this format 'company.sometext.sometext".So is there any way i can update 1.4 veriosn withour=t changing anything

Comment: I dont think so. there is no restriciton in app id as you saying only thing is it should not contain wildcar. You enable pushnotification to your existing app id itslef.

Comment: @Bangalore: there's no restriction like com.exampleApp. we've already an app with same bundle scheme, with push notification working in its 3rd version.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't enable the Push notification according to app id you never active the push notification.If you have admin role of apple developer account you can edit the app Identifier So it not effected for last version.